# Granting write access for the Authenticated Users to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to give read access to all AWS authenticated users to a bucket. Note I don't want my bucket to be publicly available. Old amazon console seems to give that provision which I no longer see -

Old S3 bucket ACL -

[image]

New bucket Acl -

[image]

How can I achieve old behavior? Can I do it using bucket policies -

Again I don't want

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1510826508027",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1510826503866",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::athakur",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That support is removed in the new s3 console and has to be set via ACL.

You can use the `put-bucket-acl` api to set the Any Authenticated AWS User as grantee.

The grantee for this is:

`<Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Group"><URI><replaceable>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers</replaceable></URI></Grantee>`

Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTacl.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks @ExploringApple for the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

We can give entire ACL string in the aws cli command as ExploringApple explained or just do -

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucketname --grant-full-control uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers
```

Docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html